# publisher subscribber pattern in nodejs sampel code is not woring with out setinterval

Tags: node.js, setinterval, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I am trying to implement pub/sub as shown below

publisher.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var pub = zmq.socket('pub');

pub.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

pub.send('pub msg');
/*
setInterval(function(){
    console.log("sending message")

},500);*/
```

subscriber.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var sub = zmq.socket('sub');
sub.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');

sub.subscribe('');  //herein lies the question

sub.on('message',function(msg){
    console.log('Received msg:',msg);
})
```

the above subscriber will receive the message only when  `pub.send('pub msg');` is inside setInterval not sure about my understanding

I dont want use setInterval  rather i have to send the message as soon it arrives

Please say how can i do it using pub/sub only i guess there is some basic understanding missing please help

in nodejs code i am trying using a route has

```
 router.post('/putMsgIn0MQ', function (req, res, next) {
     pushData(JSON.stringify(req.body))
 })

var pushData = function(dataToPush) {
    var zmqSocket = zmq.socket('pub')
        var zmqPortPart = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'
        zmqSocket.bind(zmqPortPart);
        zmqSocket.send(dataToPush);

}
```

subscriber

```
var sub = zmq.socket('sub');
                sub.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555');
                sub.subscribe('');  //herein lies the question
                console.log('Received msg:');
                sub.on('message',function(msg){
                        console.log('Received msg:');
                        console.log(msg.toString())
                        var jsonPayload = msg.toString();
                        processData(jsonPayload, zmqPortObj.name);
                })
```

Comment: You need to subscribe to the sending event. In your case, you are subscribed to nothing ( sub.subscribe(''") ).
Subscribe: sock.subscribe('kitty cats');
Publish:  sock.send(['kitty cats', 'meow!']);


'kitty cats' is the keyword here :)

Comment: when we dont specify   it means get all the message so only please say with prospect to the sample what should be the value of sub.subscribe(''")

Comment: You might be correct. But in your case, I would set a message identifier in any case.

Comment: i am  not sure how to subscribe is there a doc where i can refer and get it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this code, from their documentaiton:

```
// pubber.js 
var zmq = require('zmq')
   , sock = zmq.socket('pub');

  sock.bindSync('tcp://127.0.0.1:3000');
 console.log('Publisher bound to port 3000');

setInterval(function(){
  console.log('sending a multipart message envelope');
  sock.send(['kitty cats', 'meow!']);
}, 500);
```

It seems that setInterval is just utility function :)

What is preventing that you fire it manually?

So for example, imaginary controller:

```
exports.animals= {
   getCat: function (request, response) {

   var animal = request.payload.catStuff;

   //process the animal object
  //and manually fire the message like:


sock.send(['kitty cats', 'meow!']);

...
```

Comment: i am trying to build a module which involves no timer when ever a message is published the subscriber should get it

Comment: thanks yes i understood it is just a utility i have a route to publish the message router.post('/putMsgIn0MQ', function (req, res, next) {
    pushData(queueItem,JSON.stringify(req.body))
}) which avoid the automatic timmer the entire pubber.js is in pushData but subscriber is not receving the message not sure why is that

Comment: Please post the code you have so far, lets take a look :)